# Application has no verified creator

Tags: windows

I am creating a prank, witsh floods the screen with bananas, and ran into a problem that alway occurres, when i create applicationes.
When you try to open it, it shows a message saying:
"Are you sure that you want to open a application witch has no verified creator?"

This Message is very annoying, because, no one will open the banana prank.
Is there a way to get around this problem?

Comment: Disguise your banana program as something else :-)

Comment: no, it doesant, even though the windows security is garbage.